# There is an increase or There is an increased

Tags: grammar

I'm confused with rather using increased or increase

Example: There is an **increase** in population during the summer time.

or There is an **increased** in population during the summer time.

I know is + past particle forms passive voice but since **an** is between it, i am not sure if the rule still applies.

If both sentences are correct, what is the difference?

Comment: increase can be both a verb and a noun, you may want to check it in a dictionary!

Comment: If you want to use *increased* for this situation, you should say *The increased population.* It should modify the noun phrase. *There is an increased population during the summer time.*

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: "*There is an **increase** in population during the summer time.*" is correct. Here *increase* is used as a noun.

Longer answer:
With *increase*, the verb is written the same as the noun. And, depending on the context, *increased* is the past participle of the verb *increase* and also an adjective.

As a noun (*increase*):

> An *increase* in interest rates is expected as a result of the Reserve Bank's decision.
>   Tourist season provides a temporary *increase* in revenue for local business.
>   Improved facilities will lead to an *increase* in employee satisfaction.

As a verb (*increase*):

> We *increase* our competitive advantage by becoming more responsive to customers.
>   I *increase* my chances of getting a job by applying for the right job.
>   The water pressure *increases* as you dive deeper.

As the past participle (*increased*):

> People's life expectancy has *increased* compared to previous centuries.
>   The demand for our products has *increased*.
>   Losses for businesses have *increased* when they have not adapted to changing markets.

As an adjective (*increased*):

> People now have an *increased* life expectancy compared to previous centuries.
>   We are experiencing *increased* demand for our products.
>   Businesses can expect *increased* losses if they can't compete in today's market.